# Store and iterate through query results

Tags: java, android, cursor, mediastore

I have a music application and its worked perfectly up until now.

I have more than 1000 songs inside my SD card. Which gets displayed inside a `recycler view`.

Before I didn't need the album art for a particular song but now I want to make my app a bit better and I found a way to get album art for every song.

What I tried:

```
        ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri= MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor=contentResolver.query(musicUri,null,MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1",null,null);

        if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int imgSrcColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);

            do {
                long thisID = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = cursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = cursor.getString(artistColumn);
                long thisImg = cursor.getLong(imgSrcColumn);
                Cursor cursorx = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
                        MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?",
                        new String[] {String.valueOf(thisImg)},
                        null);

                try {
                    if (cursorx.moveToFirst()) {
                        String path = cursorx.getString(cursorx.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
                        this.songs.add(new Song(thisID, thisTitle, thisImg,thisArtist,path));
                    }
                    cursorx.close();
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Now this thing works and I get the result as expected but this takes too much time for my app to load the songs i.e. the song list.

I think other music player very much do the same but their loading time is way less. Like if I say `play music`, it takes about 2-3 seconds at max. Mine takes about 10-12 seconds, even more so.

Maybe it's because I am querying my SD card every time I need the album art.

```
Cursor cursorx = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?",
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(thisImg)},
                    null);
```

Any way to store the results and then loop through it? Like we do in `php or any other language`, get the results once from the DB and then loop through it. Instead of calling it every time.

Any better method is appreciated too!

P.s: Before using this thing ,app had the load time of 1 seconds at max.

Comment: HashMaps could be faster for it. As long as you have a key you can retrieve it quicker than having to iterate through an entire list.

Comment: Hasmaps for what? plus where i am iterating through entire list?

Comment: Store the data in a HashMap and use Strings or some other key to retrieve it. In my experience, hashmaps are faster than iterating an entire list to find a single item

Comment: but the point i am sayiing is that , filling up the list takes up time..that means if i fill a list or a hasmap, its almost same.The time spend is actually the call to the sd card every time for every song.

Comment: Don't call it every single time. That's just a waste of resources

Comment: that's what i am saying , is there any way tojust retrieve everything at once and then use it for later purposes.

The way we do in php , we get the result one time and then we work on the results.